# Signing .extension of app not in provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, signing, onesignal

I would like to export a new build of my Xcode app to iTunes Connect, but I always get the following error:

```
Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "[myappid].OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" cannot be registered to
your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string 
to try again.

Provisioning profile failed qualification
Profile doesn't include the selected signing certificate.
```

I tried the following:

- Cleaning the build
- Restart xCode
- Creating new profiles (distribution/development)
- Removing .OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension (gives another error)

I don't want to change the app id since I want to continue on the same app (for my testers).

I had to change my password of my Apple ID due to security issues, but I changed it everywhere they asked for it.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

As oneSignalNotification is an Extension, the App Id of the extension should have main App id as prefix. ie, If your main App id is : com.xx.xxapp, then the app id for your extension should be com.xx.xxapp.someExtention. Also you need to have separate provisioning profile for main App and extension target.